# Add Save and Submit Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, list-form

I have a custom form where I need to add a "Save and Submit" button that will trigger the power automate flow I created.

I want the "Save" button to only save the list item so the user can go back at a later date to edit then "Save and Submit" and trigger the approval process.

Comment: Are you using Power Apps customized SharePoint list form?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Power Apps customized SharePoint online list form in modern experience, try this:

1. Add two button control on your list form.
2. Set button text of first button control to `Save` and set it's `OnSelect` property to:

```
SubmitForm(Form1)
```

Where `Form1` is the name of your form control connected to SharePoint list.

3. Set button text of second button control to `Save and Submit` and set it's `OnSelect` property to:

```
SubmitForm(Form1);
FlowName.Run()
```

Where `FlowName` is the name of your Power Automate flow added to Power Apps customized list form.

Read more information at: [Create a canvas app that can trigger a Power Automate flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/how-to/trigger-flow)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use Power Apps and my form is being cut off. It looks like the entire form is not being loaded.

Comment: can you share screenshot? You may need to adjust the form resolution from app settings. If settings are correct, try clearing browser cache or open list form in private browser window

Comment: I am unable to share a screenshot. The form has 22 areas that a user can fill out, however only 15 are showing.  The form is not displaying the form in its entirety. I tried to clear the browser cache and adjust the form resolution and it is still not working.

Comment: if fields are arranged vertically, there should be scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I am not having any luck with Power Apps. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am using Power Automate to run an approval process when the 'Save' button is clicked, however I want to add another button to only save the list form so the user can come back to it and then submit at a later time. IDeally I want a 'Save and Submit' button to trigger the approval process and a 'Save' button to only save and NOT trigger the approval process.

Comment: For SharePoint online modern experience list forms, you can use [SPFx Form Customizer Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer). But you will need coding experience and you will have to develop everything on your own - UI/Business logic/Validation/Data Saving, etc.